# Can React context be mutated by nested component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-context

I have two components located at different places in the component tree. They ***cannot*** be nested because of layout but I need them to communicate.

I've tried React context but to my understanding the consumer needs to be a child to the provider, defeating the purpose.

Is there a way to have three components: an overarching provider, a component that will mutate the providers state and a consumer?

Pseudocode to help clarify:

```
<PROVIDER />
   <SOURCE OF DATA />
   <CONSUMER />
<PROVIDER />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, in React data always flow down the tree.

These kinds of state-management problems are really common; a lot of libraries (e.g. Redux, Mobx) have been designed to solve these issues, and I would recommend you looking into them.

However, if you really can't separate out the two components, and if you don't want to learn/include a state-management library at the moment, then you *can* use a context to thread the data though; the trick is to pass a callback function alongside the data you're threading through in the context.

When the `<SOURCE OF DATA />` component gathers new data, it can invoke this callback with the new data; this callback function (defined in the provider component) will then update the state of the provider, and that will then cause an entire refresh of all the child components with the new data values. (I've (very) roughly illustrated this below; the syntax will vary depending on whether you're using hooks or not.)

```
PROVIDER COMPONENT:
   state = data
   callback = (newData) => updateState(data <= newData)              
   return(
       <MyContext.Provide { data, callback } >     // provides { data, callback }
           <SOURCE OF DATA />   // consumes callback from context and invokes callback(newData)
           <CONSUMER />         // consumes data/newData from context
       </MyContext.Provider>
   );
```

Now if the components you've indicated above are really both 'siblings' in the provider, then you shouldn't need a context: a simple callback via props will work.

Answer (score 1):

No. In React, data always flows top-down to the rest of the tree.  Context is specifically a mechanism for making a value available to a given subtree of components.  The value for a context instance is normally kept in React component state, in the same component that renders the `<MyContext.Provider>`.  So, the state also has to live up top.

If you truly need to have widely separated components interacting with the same data like that, it's time to start looking at Redux or another external state management tool.